# Error: http://localhost/node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts: interface is a reserved word in strict mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am integrating an **AngularJS** application within an **Umbraco** project. I have a cs-html file which calls the main.js file of my app and the aplication displays in a designated URL( All this after the project has run tsc and build).

The folder structure is as follows:

```
UmbracoProject/
              |
              | angularCode/
              |              src/
              |              systemjs-angular-loader.js
              |              systemjs.config.js
              |              tsconfig.js
              |
              |node_modules/
                           @types/node/index.d.ts
```

I have to configure the **systemjs.config.js** file so that the **imports** from the angular app isable to find the node_modules. (It is set this way because there will be other angular apps in the same project so that all share the same node_modules).

I am using some of the dependencies for fabric.js require the **@types/node/index.d.ts** file in order to run.

My [systemjs.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZLC2.png) must find the following

When i go to the designed url, I recieve the following error:

```
Error: http://localhost/node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts: interface is a reserved word in strict mode (18:0)
  16 | 
  17 | // This needs to be global to avoid TS2403 in case lib.dom.d.ts is present in the same build
  18 | interface Console {
     | ^
  19 |     Console: typeof NodeJS.Console;
  20 |     assert(value: any, message?: string, ...optionalParams: any[]): void;
  21 |     dir(obj: any, options?: NodeJS.InspectOptions): void;
  Instantiating http://localhost/node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts
```

Any leads on this kind of issue?

Thanks

Comment: Are you downloading the `index.d.ts` file to the browser? Verify this, because browsers don't understand TypeScript code.

Comment: No, i am adding it as a mapping reference in my systemjs.config.js. All my other dependencies have *.umd.js or *.js but it seems that @types/node is only *.ts.

I had a previous error that required a *transpiler* in the systemjs.config.js for it to fix it. After that ... the current error is what i get.

Comment: If you ad .ts files to your system.config.js I'd say they're delivered to the browser. Can you post that file? Also, check in the network panel that System.js isn't dowloading .ts files. I really suspect it does, and hence the error when the browser tries to process them

Comment: I posted the file below.

Answer (score 0):

This is my systemjs.config.js file:

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({

    useBundles:'true',

    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': '/node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {


      // our app is within the app folder
        'app': '/LayoutEditor/Client/',

        'plugin-babel': 'npm:/systemjs-plugin-babel/plugin-babel.js',
        'systemjs-babel-build': 'npm:/systemjs-plugin-babel/systemjs-babel-browser.js',
        'systemjs': 'npm:/systemjs/dist/system.js',
        'system-polyfills': 'npm:/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
        'es6-module-loader': 'npm:/es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.js',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/common/http': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-http.umd.js',

      //angular material and angular./cdk
      '@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',
      '@angular/material/core': 'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material-core.umd.js',
      '@angular/material/icon':'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material-icon.umd.js',
      '@angular/material/button':'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material-button.umd.js',
      '@angular/material/menu':'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material-menu.umd.js',
      '@angular/material/list': 'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material-list.umd.js',
      '@angular/material/toolbar':'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material-toolbar.umd.js',
      '@angular/material/expansion':'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material-expansion.umd.js',
      '@angular/material/form-field':'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material-form-field.umd.js',
      '@angular/material/input':'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material-input.umd.js',
      '@angular/material/tooltip':'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material-tooltip.umd.js',
      '@angular/material/chips':'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material-chips.umd.js',
      '@angular/material/sidenav':'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material-sidenav.umd.js',
      '@angular/material/dialog':'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material-dialog.umd.js',
      '@angular/material/grid-list':'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material-grid-list.umd.js',
      '@angular/material/progress-spinner':'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material-progress-spinner.umd.js',
      '@angular/material/checkbox':'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material-checkbox.umd.js',
      '@angular/material/slide-toggle':'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material-slide-toggle.umd.js',
      '@angular/material/card':'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material-card.umd.js',
      '@angular/material/divider' :'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material-divider.umd.js',
        // angular/cdk
        '@angular/cdk': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/bidi': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-bidi.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/a11y': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-a11y.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/coercion': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-coercion.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/keycodes': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-keycodes.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/overlay': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-overlay.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/portal': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-portal.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/accordion': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-accordion.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/layout': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-layout.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/collections': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-collections.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/observers': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-observers.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/scrolling': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-scrolling.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/table': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-table.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/stepper': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-stepper.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/platform': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-platform.umd.js',


      //angular animations
      '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
      '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',


      //authentication provider
        'angular-oauth2-oidc': 'npm:angular-oauth2-oidc/angular-oauth2-oidc.umd.js',


        //fabricjs and canvas
        'fabric': 'npm:fabric/dist/fabric.js',
        'canvas': 'npm:canvas/index.js',
        'xmldom': 'npm:xmldom/dom.js',
        'url': 'npm:url/url.js',
        'jsdom': 'npm:jsdom/lib/jsdom.js',
        'https': 'npm:@types/node/index.d.ts',
        'http': 'npm:@types/node/index.d.ts',
        'fs': 'npm:@types/node/index.d.ts',



      // other libraries
      'tslib': 'npm:tslib/tslib.js',
      'angular-persistence': 'angular-persistence',
      'rxjs':'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'ngx-color-picker': 'npm:ngx-color-picker/bundles/ngx-color-picker.umd.js',
      'ng2-scroll-to-el': 'npm:ng2-scroll-to-el/bundles/ngScrollTo.umd.js',
      'angular2-draggable': 'npm:angular2-draggable/bundles/angular2-draggable.umd.js',
      'sweetalert2': 'npm:sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js',
      'file-saver': 'npm:file-saver/dist/FileSaver.js',
      'ngresizable': 'npm:ngresizable/ngresizable.bundle.js'



      },

     transpiler: 'plugin-babel',

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        meta: {
          './LayoutEditor/Client/*.js': {
              loader: '/LayoutEditor/systemjs-angular-loader.js'
            }
        }
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
        }

    }
  });
})(this);
```

I think the problem seems to be the transpiler setup.